# The 'BillingPhysicalMedicineId' property on 'GetPhysicalMedicineInfoByOrderNo_Result' could not be set to a 'System.Int32' value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server SP in which I am returning a column value as 0 if the value is NULL in that column.

The type of column in database is bigint which is equivalent to long/Int64 in C#, when I map the SP to EF model the type of the fields, it is also showing correctly i.e. long in the return type generated by the EF model.

However when I call the SP from C# using EF function call it is giving me the above error.

This is happening only when the val;ue returned is 0, however it works fine if the value returned in the column is other than 0.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Code of the stored procedure would help, as would the (generated) mapping code. One obvious pitfall would be that you cannot use the stored procedure's return value (i.e. what you return with `RETURN`), as that can only ever be `INT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So after a lot of digging and searching through of tons of online articles I came to a conclusion that @JeroenMostert comments really make sense. And based on that I had to cast the value of that column to bigint in all my SPs wherever the data type is bigint, otherwise it was assuming the returned values as int only.

```
CAST(0 as bigint) As BillingPhysicalMedicineId
```

Home it helps other folks as well.